# Configure ActionMailer to send mails using 1&1 SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, sendmail, actionmailer

I'm trying to configure ActionMailer to send mails using the SMTP server by 1&1. I've read the [instructions provided by 1&1](https://help.1and1.com/e-mail-c37589/1and1-e-mail-c37590/using-the-product-c85088/e-mail-software-setup-credentials-a616889.html) and all SO questions and answers on this subject, but I'm not able to configure it.

Here's my configuration (in `config/environments/development.rb`):

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.1and1.com",
    :domain => "1and1.com",
    :port      => "25",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => 'MY_EMAIL@MY_DOMAIN.COM,
    :password  => 'MY_PASSWORD'
  }
```

This doesn't work. Other things I unsuccessfully tried:

- Set `port` to `587`
- Set `authentication` to `:plain`

---

This is what happens: when the `deliver` method is executed, it hangs for 10 seconds or so, and then it ends without apparently failing, outputting this to the log:

```
Sent mail to SOME_EMAIL@SOMEDOMAIN.COM (30041.5ms)
```

but I don't receive the mails. BTW, Configuring it with gmail works, and the log output is the same.

Has anyone successfully configure it?

**EDIT 1:** I've checked the logs again. I found this:

```
[...] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 535 Authentication failure
```

**EDIT 2:** Using port 25 the log is:

```
[...] Timeout::Error: execution expired
```

**EDIT 3:** Using `:address => "auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk"` **works**. Is it a 1&1 issue then?

Answer (score 1):

This does it for me:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.1and1.com",
    :port      => 25,
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :user_name => 'MY_EMAIL@MY_DOMAIN.COM,
    :password  => 'MY_PASSWORD'
}
```

// SMTP CODE 535 means just bad username/password. Make sure to use the whole maila ddress as a username.

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work for me. Is your username the email address (created within the 1&1 panel)? And the password, the password assigned to that email address? In other words, are they the credentials you use to login in the using webmail?

Comment: Please see the EDIT 1 of my question

Comment: see edit. Have you tried `:plain` instead of `:login`?

Comment: Yes I'm using `:plain`. Both `:user_name`and `:password` are OK, I'm using them to log in the webmail (full username, with `@` and `domain.com`). See my EDIT 2. Does it matter to use port 25 or 857?

Comment: Im using 25, try to type it as a `Fixnum` and not `String`. Also try ' plain' instead of :plain like in my edited post

Answer (score 1):

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk',
  domain:               '1and1.com',
  port:                 587,  
  authentication:       'login',
  user_name:            'email@domain.com',
  password:             'password',
  }
```

this works for me and make sure to configure the default

> default from: "email@domain.com"